# Update List of classes with data from a list of classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
public class DataMember {
    public string ID{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

And another class:

```
public class MasterDataMember {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> FoundVersions { get; set; }
}
```

I store both sets of data in a Cache as:

```
List<DataMember> datamembers
List<MasterDataMember> masterdatamembers
```

When originally built, the MasterDataMember is a list of partial "versions". These versions need to be confirmed and found in the list of DataMember's.

How can I update masterdatamembers with the confirmed versions found in datamembers?
(this code block is untested but it illustrates what I'm trying to do)

```
foreach (MasterDataMember item in masterdatamembers) {
    List<string> confirmedvers = new List<string>();
    foreach(string rawver in item.FoundVersions ){
        foreach(DataMember checkitem in datamembers){
            foreach (string confirmedver in checkitem.Versions) {
                if (rawver.Contains(confirmedver)) {
                    confirmedvers.Add(confirmedver);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    item.FoundVersions = vers;
}
```

Is there a LINQ that can accomplish this a lot easier, faster (I've already tried lots of ideas, iterations)?

Speed is the key here since both lists can be hundreds to thousands long.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a `HashSet<T>` instead of a `List<T>`?

Comment: No, I haven't... lemme look it up! Thanks!

Comment: HashSet would help in other areas. I've never used it before but will be from now on. But it doesn't help here where I need to do a comparison that checks if one is contained in the other. I don't see how a HashSet would simplify this or make it faster.

Comment: Confirm if I got this right: For every MasterDataMember, you want to find the matching DataMember (they match according to their ID property I take it?).  If you find a matching DataMember, then you want to take that DataMember's list of versions and copy them over to the MasterDataMember, effectively replacing what was there before?  Or do you want to add them to the existing list in MasterDataMember? (I'm ignoring your code block because it doens't seem to do what you describe in the text, that's why I'm asking for clarification).

Comment: @sstan almost... if there is a matching ID, find if any of the DataMember versions will `contains()` any of the MasterDataMember versions. That's why I have the code block there to illustrate this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If speed *really* is your primary concern because of large lists, then you'll want to use hash table constructs.  Using LINQ is slick, but won't necessarily make things faster (or clearer) for you. What you really need is to use the proper collection type.

**Assumptions made for the code that follows:**

- `datamembers` cache cannot have duplicate `DataMember` entries (where more than one entry has the same ID).
- `masterdatamembers` cache cannot have duplicate `MasterDataMember` entries (where more than one entry has the same ID).
- In both `DataMember` and `MasterDataMember`, the `Versions` and `FoundVersions` lists cannot have duplicate version entries.

**Algorithm Description**

I still feel that your code block doesn't quite reflect your intent.  And unfortunately, as a result, I think you got wrong answers.

This is the algorithm I followed, based on trying to interpret your intended result:

For each master data member, update its `FoundVersions` set (or list) by only keeping the versions in the list that can also be found in the matching data member's `Versions` set (or list).  If no matching data member is found, then I assume you want the master data members `FoundVersions` set (or list) to be emptied, as none of the versions can be confirmed.

**Implementation**

Notice that I replaced a few uses of `List<T>` with `Dictionary<K, V>` or `HashSet<T>` where it would benefit performance.  Of course, I am assuming that your lists can become large as you said.  Otherwise, the performance will be similar as simple lists.

Your 2 classes, (notice the change in types):

```
public class DataMember
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> Versions { get; set; } // using hashset is faster here.
}

public class MasterDataMember
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> FoundVersions { get; set; } // used HashSet for consistency, but for the purposes of the algorithm, a List can still be used here if you want.
}
```

Your cached data, (notice the change to a Dictionary):

```
Dictionary<string, DataMember> datamembers; // using a Dictionary here, where your key is the DataMember's ID, is your fastest option.
List<MasterDataMember> masterdatamembers; // this can stay as a list if you want.
```

And finally, the work is done here:

```
foreach (var masterDataMember in masterdatamembers)
{
    DataMember dataMember;
    if (datamembers.TryGetValue(masterDataMember.ID, out dataMember))
    {
        HashSet<string> newSet = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var version in masterDataMember.FoundVersions)
        {
            if (dataMember.Versions.Contains(version))
            {
                newSet.Add(version);
            }
        }

        masterDataMember.FoundVersions = newSet;
    }
    else
    {
        masterDataMember.FoundVersions.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may owe you a six pack. Your assumptions are correct. If I was unclear, I apologize. Sometimes it can be hard to isolate the description of a problem when it's part of a much larger system. You're causing me to re-think my whole setup. It may take me a while, but I promise to come back and accept the one that I used. THANK YOU so much for this very clear explanation. I get hashes from way back when I was first looking into Python. So this makes sense. I wish I had enough points to up-vote as I also like the other two answers here and they will be useful in other ways!

Comment: I actually used two answers here. But this one was the one that made the biggest impact to my code. Thank you @sstan.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (MasterDataMember item in masterdatamembers) {
    IEnumerable<string> confirmedvers = item.FoundVersions.Where(rawver => rawver.Any(confirmedver => datamembers.Any(checkitem => checkitem.Versions.Contains(rawver)));
}
```

HOLY crap bro that was confusing as hell for me!

Awesome mind experiment though!

Comment: Yeah, I was going crazy and needed to write out the problem and get input. So, using your code, what I could do is actually: instead of `cofirmedvers = ` I could use `item.FoundVersions = `

Comment: I haven't ran and compiled it yet but I had to add a closing paren ) and add ToList() to get it show up error free in the IDE... FYI :) I'm compiling and running now.

Comment: Yea i do all this from the top of my head.. ;)

Comment: well, it compiles and it runs! I'm just trying confirm if any data changed hands. It seems like it ran too fast... if you know what I mean. Don't worry, if I use it will accept the answer. THANKS a mill.!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like something like this in Linq

```
masterDataMembers.ForEach(q=>q.FoundVersions = (from rawver in q.FoundVersions from checkitem in dataMembers from confirmedver in checkitem.Versions where rawver.Contains(confirmedver) select confirmedver).ToList());
```

Comment: Dude! I didn't know you could do that with a `ForEach`!